# WinForms C# Entity Framework combobox

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, frameworks, entity

I'm building a Win Form app using Entity Framework. I have followed [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj682076(v=vs.113).aspx) example. In the Main Form I double click a Product record to open the specific product in a separate Products Form where I can update it using textboxes and a combobox. All the controls in Products Form are populated correctly. The problem is on the Categories combobox when I try to Save the record. I cannot change the Product category because the combobox retains the initial value.
Thanks in advance.
Chris.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace WinFormswithEFSample
{
    public partial class ProductsFrm : Form
    {
        ProductContext _context;
        int prodId;

        public ProductsFrm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public ProductsFrm(string id)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Int32.TryParse(id, out int idInt);
            prodId = idInt;
        }

        private void PopulateFields()
        {
            //select single product by ID
            var selectedProduct = _context.Products.Find(prodId);

            //select categories for combo
            var allCategories = _context.Categories.Local.ToList();

            string categID = selectedProduct.CategoryId.ToString();
            Int32.TryParse(categID, out int categIDInt);
            PopulateComboCategory(_context, categIDInt);
            this.comboCategory.SelectedValue = categIDInt;

            //Bind controls
            this.txtProductID.DataBindings.Add("Text", selectedProduct, "ProductId");
            this.txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", selectedProduct, "Name");
            this.comboCategory.DataBindings.Add("Text", allCategories, "CategoryId",true); //,DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged

        }

        private void PopulateComboCategory(ProductContext _cont, int catID)
        {
            //var products = _cont.Categories.Where(p => p.CategoryId == catID).ToList();
            var categories = _cont.Categories.ToList();
            this.comboCategory.DataSource = categories;
            this.comboCategory.ValueMember = "CategoryId";
            this.comboCategory.DisplayMember = "Name";

        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);
            _context = new ProductContext();
            _context.Products.Load();

            this.productBindingSource.DataSource =
                _context.Products.Local.ToBindingList();

            PopulateFields();
        }

        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnClosing(e);
            this._context.Dispose();
        }

        private void cmdSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SaveProduct();
        }

        private void SaveProduct()
        {

            this.Validate();

            foreach (var product in _context.Products.Local.ToList())
            {
                if (product.Category == null)
                {
                    _context.Products.Remove(product);
                }
            }

            // Save the changes to the database.
            this._context.SaveChanges();

            // Refresh the controls to show the values         
            // that were generated by the database.
            this._context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Most likely `categIDInt` has no value.

Comment: Hi Yoshi. categIDInt has a value. My product has the correct category value on load but it retains it even if I change it on the combo box...

Comment: I ended up adding a hidden textbox and assigning the combobox SelectedValue on SelectedIndexChanged to the textbox. It worked but this is less than ideal... I would like to know why DbContext seem to be agnostic of the combobox value change during Save...

Comment: At this line `this.comboCategory.SelectedValue = categIDInt;`, make sure `categIDInt` has a value and it is an integer and the datasource has that value. Also, make sure the `CategoryId` is also of type `integer`. If the types are not the same, it will not work. Finally try `int categIDInt; Int32.TryParse(categID, out categIDInt);` and make sure the parsing is successful. If not successful, show a message box for testing purposes.

Comment: Hi Yoshi. categIDInt has a value and it's integer. If by 'datasource has that value' you mean the ID in the database, then yes, this is an existing ID value on the DB and it is integer. I know that the parsed value is an int because I assign it to the prodId global int variable. Declaring the categIDInt outside the TryParse didn't have any effect. You may find the whole app [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1BjESoYewgxZTlSI1Z28B9N-46-odd3ue/view?usp=sharing) if you want to have a closer look. Thanks for your help anyway!